how to calculate longitude & latitude From a source longitude, Latitude, angle(degree) & distance(length)
How to calculate Destination:(longitude & latitude precisely)
From a source :(longitude, Latitude, angle (degree) & distance
(length - direct, not through navigation path via road, direct geometric distance)
a code, with or without using 3rd party libraries (MapKit preferable)

It can be done wihout a libary, but that is some serious geospatial Mathematics :). There is many libraries for that, and turf.js is one of the simplest to use and install: https://github.com/Turfjs/turf . I believe you are looking for the method "distance", you might find other helpful utilities in there for your app: https://turfjs.org/docs/api/distance

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Thankyou for your reply, this not quite what I am looking for ,
a simple code snippet cos,sin,atan etc ,(preferably in SWIFT)
